# CSS "table-cell" styled element: Maximum height (and overflow: hidden)

Tags: css

I have a `display: table-cell` div inside a `display: table` div. Is there any way to limit the height? I've tried setting height, max-height, and overflow: hidden, but it has no effect. (`height` does set the minimum height, but the others seem to do nothing.

See example at http://jsbin.com/gajaka/1/edit

```
<div class='table'>
  <div class='cell'>This should be maximum 100px. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.table {
  display: table;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px; /* ignored */
  overflow: hidden; /* ignored */
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100px; /* ignored */  
  text-align: center; /* doesn't work */  
}
```

Comment: `table-cell` => Let the element behave like a `<td>` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see with this code, it appears you are using the table cell display in order to vertically align the text. However, table-cell comes with the inherent tradeoff that you lose control of the y-dimension; that is, the table-cell will ignore all height parameters, as you've seen.

The way to fix this would be to change the `display` sub-attribute from `table-cell` to `inline-block`. Then, in order to get the vertical centering, we can do the following: Place a pseudo-element inside the `.table` element and vertically align this. Vertical align needs to be relative to another inline element, so this pseudo-element gives a reference for the `.cell` to vertically align itself against. This should vertically align your text.

New output: http://jsbin.com/faqadumasado/1/edit?html,css,output

Article on "Centering in the Unknown" that describes the vertical centering technique above: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Thanks, I did want confirmation that height is ignored here and also didn't realise `display: table` would be any use in the absence of a `display: table-cell` child.